# Exporting More Info Row to PDF using LogiXML not showing up

Tags: sql, .net, xml, pdf, export

I am having some trouble trying to export a report to PDF format.  I have an action report element to show the more info row, meaning, it is hidden by default (Show Mode : None) until the user clicks a particular element.  However, this is creating problems when trying to export since, when I check the option in the Target.PDF element as to "Keep Show Elements", I'm coming up with a blank page.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to troubleshoot these types of export problems is to start simplifying the definition file so that you can easily isolate the issue.  For your reports, I might start by remarking the MoreInfoRow so that it's effectively not impacting the export.

-Does the report export to PDF once the MoreInfoRow is gone?  If yes, the we can assume the problem has to do with the MoreInfoRow.  If no, then there is a different issue.   If you've removed the MoreInfoRow and it still doesn't export properly, I might guess that the problem is either :  1) You're passing incorrect showmodes with the export  or 2) the report requires parameters to be passed with the Action PDF as well that aren't getting set properly.

For additional details on ShowModes, I'd visit:

http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1043

If the MoreInfoRow is the problem, you might try simplifying the report, in general.  Here's a quick example that you can try:

```
<Report ID="Default" SavedBy="test">
  <StyleSheet Theme="SimpleBlue" />
  <Body>
    <Label Caption="Export PDF" Class="ThemeLinkButton">
      <Action Type="PDF">
        <Target Type="PDF" KeepShowElements="True" Report="CurrentReport" />
      </Action>
    </Label>
    <LineBreak LineCount="3" />
    <DataTable ID="dtExport" Width="450">
      <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="myData1">
        <StaticDataRow id="001" name="Sample Row 1" />
        <StaticDataRow id="002" name="Sample Row 2" />
        <StaticDataRow id="003" name="Sample Row 3" />
      </DataLayer>
      <DataTableColumn ID="colid" Header="id">
        <Label ID="lblid" Caption="@Data.id~">
          <Action Type="ShowElement" ElementID="mirTest" ID="actShowMir" />
        </Label>
      </DataTableColumn>
      <DataTableColumn ID="colname" Header="name">
        <Label ID="lblname" Caption="@Data.name~" />
      </DataTableColumn>
      <MoreInfoRow ShowModes="None" ID="mirTest">
        <Label Caption="This is the More Info Row" />
      </MoreInfoRow>
    </DataTable>
  </Body>
</Report>
```

Comment: As you have correctly pointed out, I believe my problem is with ShowModes.  The problem (which I forgot to mention) is that, when I enable, "Keep Show Elements" on the Target.PDF I get a completely blank report with nothing showing up, if I remove it, I obtain the main report (with no MoreInfoRows even if they are visible on the browser).  

PS: I also have charts (inside subreports) which become visible upon clicking which have a ShowMode of "None", will this create an issue as well?

Thanks for your assistance! You always answer my questions promptly and are of great help